# How to calculate v min and v max for C51 DQN

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, probability-distribution

**Background:** In C51 DQNs you must specify a v-min/max to be used during training. The way this is generally done is you take the max score possible for the game and set that to v-max, then v-min is just negative v-max. For a game like Pong deciding the v-min/max is simple because the max score possible is 20, therefore, `v_min=-20` and `v_max=20`.

**Question:** In a game like Space Invaders, there is no max score, so how would I calculate the v-min/max for a C51 DQN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a discount factor less than 1, you should be able to compute a maximum return (likewise, a minimum return) based on the max (min) reward you can earn at each timestep. However, this issue you bring up is usually cited as a difficulty with C51. I think people tend to simply use fixed values for the min/max return (or just make rough estimates). If you want to avoid this, I recommend looking into the QR-DQN algorithm which circumvents this issue altogether and is more theoretically sound.